# В Wordpress после кеширования wp super cache перестали работать кастомные стили

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, кэширование

После процесса кеширования, плагином `wp super cache` на сайте перестали отображаться стили кастомного `css` файла, хотя до этого все работало нормально.

То есть файл загружается, его можно посмотреть в панели разработчика, но при этом этом элементы `DOM`, не видят данных стилей. Я пробовал закидывать эти стили в конец основного `css` файла `style.css` в корне темы, но результатов это никаких не дало, тогда я кинул эти стили в футер в тег `style` - тоже не заработало.

Что в делать в данной ситуации, так как я понимаю проблема не в кешировании `css`?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения] - объявление файла стилей, дальше его содержимое и результат.

Comment: Странные вещи вы говорите - в браузере стили есть, а на сайте не отображается. Покажите, как это, картинкой ) А вообще-то, при использовании wp super cache кэширование надо выключать на время разработки, а потом включать снова. Ну, и ctrl+f5 постоянно

Comment: @KAGGDesign та уже после отключения и даже удаления плагина все равно стили не пашут.

Comment: а потому что файл стилей с ошибками. У вас в 85 строке `@media (min-width: 980px) and (max-width: 1023px) {` и эта скобка не закрыта до самого конца файла. Ни плагин, ни браузер не виноваты.

Comment: Огромное спасибо!